# Access EventEmitter Service inside of CustomHttp

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have created custom interceptor for all Http requests:

```
import {EventEmitterService} from "./EventEmitter.service";

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, _eventEmitterService:EventEmitterService) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }
 get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return super.get(url,{headers: interceptorHeaders}).catch((res)=>{
            if (res.status === 403){
                console.log("Interceptor here")
                this._eventEmitterService.logout.emit("403");
            }
            return Observable.of(res);
        });
    }
}
```

Which works great - whenever I am receiving a 403 response from the server I get :

```
Interceptor here
```

in my console.

However, there is an issue with injecting `EventEmitterService` into the catch function. Whenever I am inside of it, I cant access `CustomHttp` - I only have access to some `Observable`, even though when I debug my constructor - I can see the `EventEmitterService` has been injected.

This is how I inject `EventEmitterService`:

```
bootstrap(App,[...,
EventEmitterService,
    new Provider(Http, {
        useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, _eventEmitterService:EventEmitterService) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions,_eventEmitterService),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions,EventEmitterService]
    }),...]);
```

Comment: Don't use EventEmitter in your services, use Observables directly.

Comment: Alright. How can I then intercept response with status 403 and notify other component/injectable that this status was received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you just missed the `private` keyword at the level of the `_eventEmitterService` parameter of the `CustomHttp` constructor:

```
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
            defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
            private _eventEmitterService:EventEmitterService) { // <----
  super(backend, defaultOptions);
}
```

Comment: So easy. I thought that public (default), and private in constructor were only important for TypeScript, not for the compiled javascript.